# /etc/profile has error. Can someone fix it

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, scripts

```
nd Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
 fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: just put a hash `#` preceding the first line, it should be a comment

Comment: @siloko: I think that's the answer here. Could you please convert your comment into an answer post?

Answer (score 4):

The first line of your file should be a comment but is missing the preceding `#`. In fact to return your file to it's default state replace the first line with the following:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
```